# Torrents for latest database dumps

Tags: support, data-dump

Are the data dumps available as torrents?

The official location for the database dumps appears to be [here](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange), but they are direct HTTP links, and some of the files are quite large (over 10 GB for Stack Overflow posts, for example).

I have had some bad luck downloading big files directly and would much prefer torrents (or any other method that can reliably continue interrupted downloads and recover from minor corruption). It wouldn't even need to be the most recent, anything from the last year or so would be sufficient.

Comment: [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) can handle restarting failed downloads. See *[Robustness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget#Robustness)*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Or any vaguely competent program calling itself a download manager, for that matter.